# PostgreSQL: prevent lock on self table update with left join

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, left-join, self-join

I'm on PostgreSQL 9.3. I'm the only one working on the database, and my code run queries sequentially for unit tests.

Most of the times the following UPDATE query run without problem, but sometimes it makes locks on the PostgreSQL server. And then the query seems to never ends, while it takes only 3 sec normally.
I must precise that the query run in a unit test context, i.e. data is exactly the same whereas the lock happens or not. The code is the only process that updates the data.

I know there may be lock problems with PostgreSQL when using update query for a self updating table. And most over when a LEFT JOIN is used.

I also know that a LEFT JOIN query can be replaced with a NOT EXISTS query for an UPDATE but in my case the LEFT JOIN is much faster because there is few data to update, while a NOT EXISTS should visit quite all row candidates.

**So my question is:** what PostgreSQL commands (like Explicit Locking `LOCK` on table) or options (like `SELECT FOR UPDATE`) I should use in order to ensure to run my query without never-ending lock.

Query:

```
-- for each places of scenario #1 update all owners that
-- are different from scenario #0
UPDATE t_territories AS upt
SET id_owner = diff.id_owner
FROM (
    -- list of owners in the source that are different from target
    SELECT trg.id_place, src.id_owner
    FROM t_territories AS trg
    LEFT JOIN t_territories AS src
       ON  (src.id_scenario = 0)
       AND (src.id_place = trg.id_place)
    WHERE (trg.id_scenario = 1)
    AND (trg.id_owner IS DISTINCT FROM src.id_owner)
    -- FOR UPDATE -- bug SQL : FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
) AS diff
WHERE (upt.id_scenario = 1)
AND (upt.id_place = diff.id_place)
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t_territories
(
  id_scenario integer NOT NULL,
  id_place integer NOT NULL,
  id_owner integer,
  CONSTRAINT t_territories_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_scenario, id_place),
  CONSTRAINT t_territories_fkey_owner FOREIGN KEY (id_owner)
      REFERENCES t_owner (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

Comment: One session alone can *never* be blocked. Check `pg_locks` from a second session. Also see if the query is running, i.e. if the process is consuming CPU time.

Comment: IIUC, your subquery can yield more than one value for each id_place, causing repetitive updates per {id_scenario,id_place} (and your `trg`-tuple in the subquery refers to exactly the same tuple as the `upt` in the target RTE)

Comment: But, if your intention is to set `upt.id_owner` to NULL if no corresponding row exists with `id_scenario=1`, it would IMO be easier to update from a scalar (correlated) subquery.

Comment: @joop « your subquery can yield more than one value for each id_place » I don't think so because (id_scenario, id_place) is a primary key, so the sub-query get only a liste of id_place for scenario #1. And most over, the query run ok most of the time with the exactly same same (it's a units test script).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : the locking effectively happens when there is another session, but just a pgAdmin III session for the database browser, and a SELECT query which is terminated and both are state `idle`.
But it is SELECT queries and plus there are inactive.
Here are the lock info from `pg_locks` and pgAdmin 4. Not so useful for me.
https://imgur.com/a/JBYha
https://imgur.com/a/kUIeu

Comment: @Skrol29 There are no locks that block (`granted = false`). Maybe the statement just takes a long time. On the other hand, maybe you looked at `pg_locks` when nothing was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query was locked by another query. You can find this query by

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(blockingl.relation::regclass::text,blockingl.locktype) as locked_item,
  now() - blockeda.query_start AS waiting_duration, blockeda.pid AS blocked_pid,
  blockeda.query as blocked_query, blockedl.mode as blocked_mode,
  blockinga.pid AS blocking_pid, blockinga.query as blocking_query,
  blockingl.mode as blocking_mode
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks blockedl
JOIN pg_stat_activity blockeda ON blockedl.pid = blockeda.pid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks blockingl ON(
  ( (blockingl.transactionid=blockedl.transactionid) OR
  (blockingl.relation=blockedl.relation AND blockingl.locktype=blockedl.locktype)
  ) AND blockedl.pid != blockingl.pid)
JOIN pg_stat_activity blockinga ON blockingl.pid = blockinga.pid
  AND blockinga.datid = blockeda.datid
WHERE NOT blockedl.granted
AND blockinga.datname = current_database()
```

This query I've found here http://big-elephants.com/2013-09/exploring-query-locks-in-postgres/

Also can use ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK to prevent any query to read and write table `t_territories`

```
LOCK t_territories IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

More info about locks here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: Unfortunately your query return no rows when the lock happens and I can see it with `pg_locks` and pgAdmin 4. The query return nothing even if I remove the WHERE clause.